# Django full text search with PostgreSQL, across multiple different models

Tags: django, postgresql, full-text-search

I need to perform FTS across multiple different models. I want to get any model type in search result.

I would like to sort results by rank, to get most relevant result. I can run search one by one, but not sure how can I combine results, especially preserving rank relevancy.

Here are models, its an example from Making queries manual page.

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()


class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()


class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    mod_date = models.DateField()
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    number_of_comments = models.IntegerField()
    number_of_pingbacks = models.IntegerField()
    rating = models.IntegerField()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine your multiple querysets into one with something like this.

```
from itertools import chain

blogs = Blog.objects.filter(...)
authors = Author.objects.filter(...)
entries = Entry.objects.search(...)

chain = chain(blog_results, lesson_results, profile_results)
qs = sorted(chain, key=lambda instance: instance.pk, reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the [QuerySet.union](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#union) operator, you can combine QuerySets from different models as long as the resulting `SELECT` of your query uses the same types.

The author of [this blog post](https://simonwillison.net/2017/Oct/5/django-postgresql-faceted-search/#Searching_multiple_tables_using_querysetunion_192) has a neat example using `SearchRank` and `SearchQuery` (you don't need these however, this could also be a simple filter). Note that you need to use the same values on each model `('pk', 'type', 'rank')` in order for `.union()` to work. The `type` annotation informs about the model which was returned

This allows you to have sorting, limiting and maybe even further filtering on the database side instead of in Django.

Query from the article:

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchRank, SearchQuery  # not in the article, but implied

query = SearchQuery('django')
rank_annotation = SearchRank(F('search_document'), query)

qs = Blogmark.objects.annotate(
    rank=rank_annotation,
    type=models.Value('blogmark', output_field=models.CharField())
).filter(
    search_document=query
).values('pk', 'type', 'rank').union(
    Entry.objects.annotate(
        rank=rank_annotation,
        type=models.Value('entry', output_field=models.CharField())
    ).filter(
        search_document=query
    ).values('pk', 'type', 'rank'),
    Quotation.objects.annotate(
        rank=rank_annotation,
        type=models.Value('quotation', output_field=models.CharField())
    ).filter(
        search_document=query
    ).values('pk', 'type', 'rank'),
).order_by('-rank')[:5]
```

Results from the article:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'pk': 186, 'type': u'quotation', 'rank': 0.875179},
    {'pk': 134, 'type': u'quotation', 'rank': 0.842655},
    {'pk': 1591, 'type': u'entry', 'rank': 0.804502},
    {'pk': 5093, 'type': u'blogmark', 'rank': 0.788616},
    {'pk': 2598, 'type': u'blogmark', 'rank': 0.786928}
]>
```